# AVAudioPlayer suddenly no longer plays entire audio source

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I am using an AVAudioPlayer to play audio in my app, and it worked for a while. Suddenly, it just stopped working and I cannot figure out why. I created the AVAudioPlayer at the class level in the .h file. This is the code I use to init the player

```
-(void)initAudio
 {
    NSURL *song = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Prelude" withExtension:@"m4a"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:song error:&error];
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
```

I call this method in the initWithSize function. error is nil, and I have verified that the player object contains the actual audio file. The audio file plays back fine in my OS environment and I have tried adding it to the build phase compile sources just to be safe, even though beforehand it worked fine without it explicitly there. When I trigger the play event, it will play the first snippet of the audio and then nothing. I log the current time of the player and it is 0. Everything else about the app is continuing on and functions without issue. I do not interfere with the avaudioplayer object in any way except to play/pause/preparetoplay.

I am completely stumped as it worked fine and then suddenly no longer works. I have tried to clean the project, I have even dumped the derivedData.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think your player has an error when you try to play the song.

You need to check the error first.

In my opinion, it seems like OSStatus error -43.

When you update an app, file path can be changed.

For example,
old path : /var/mobile/Applications/F28E0C2C-4AE2-4C9D-906F-414AE1669D90/Documents/AAA.mp3

new path: var/mobile/Applications/6086783B-A410-42C3-9BAE-7BA755D0E528/Documents/AAA.mp3

Try this code instead:

```
 NSError *error;
 NSURL *song = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Prelude" withExtension:@"m4a"];

_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:song error:&error];

if(error){

    NSLog(@"[error localizedDescription] %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    NSString *fileName = [[song absoluteString] lastPathComponent]; //this code is just example. get your fileName like "AAA.m4a"

    NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirPath , fileName];

    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] error:&error];

    }

    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    [_audioPlayer play];

}
```

I hope this will help you.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no error at any stage in the process of the app running. I have set breakpoints and debugged at every stage. Everything loads fine and &error = nil. I guess I forgot to include that in the original text. I did not set the delegate to self though, I will try this change and see if that helps.